# Ggplot grouped by a column and y axis size adjustment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a ggplot grouped by column 1 (one chart for each stratum). But I did this arrangement of the data before plotting and so I don't know how to fit aes(color = x [, 1]) and facet_wrap (~ x [, 1]) ...

If anyone knows, I would also like to know how to adjust the size of the y axis according to the amount of species.

My data frame is:

```
#My ungrouped ggplot is:

t<-t(data.frame(dtt2[,2], dtt2[,7], dtt2[,9], dtt2[,11]))
t<-data.frame(t)

rownames(t)[2]<-"Densidade Relativa"
rownames(t)[3]<-"Dominancia Relativa"
rownames(t)[4]<-"Frequencia Relativa"

specie <- t(data.frame(rep(t[1,], each=3)))
value<-data.frame(b=unlist(t[2:4,],use.names=F))
condition <- data.frame(rep(rownames(t[2:4,]),ncol(t)))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)

data$b<-as.character(data$b)
data$b<-as.numeric(data$b)
colnames(data)[1]<-"Especies"
colnames(data)[2]<-"Parametros"

margins = unit(c(1, 1, 3, 1), 'lines')


  gg<-ggplot(data, aes(reorder(Especies,b), b, fill = Parametros)) +
    geom_col(alpha = 0.8) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
    theme_bw(16)  +
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("Especies") + ylab("Indice de Valor de Importancia (%)") +
    labs(fill = "Parametros") +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic",size=10), legend.title=element_blank(),legend.justification = "left" ,legend.text=element_text(size=10),
          axis.text.x= element_text(size=10), axis.title.x=element_text(size=12),
          axis.title.y=element_text(size=12),
          plot.margin=margins,legend.position=c(-0.5,-0.2),legend.direction = "horizontal")


> dtt2
   Estrato                  Especie  n     G UA DA..n.ha. DR.... DoA..G.ha.
1        1     Caryocar brasiliense 46 1.996  6     1.704 15.808      0.074
2        1        Qualea parviflora 77 0.329  6     2.852 26.460      0.012
3        1  Stenocalyx dysentericus 54 0.292  6     2.000 18.557      0.011
4        1       Pouteria ramiflora 18 0.173  4     0.667  6.186      0.006
5        1 Sclerolobium paniculatum 10 0.262  4     0.370  3.436      0.010
6        1       Astronium balansae 10 0.178  5     0.370  3.436      0.007
7        1  Andira cujabensis Benth  7 0.025  5     0.259  2.405      0.001
8        1            Annona Cacans  7 0.036  3     0.259  2.405      0.001
9        1     Hymenaea stilbocarpa  7 0.026  3     0.259  2.405      0.001
10       1   Bowdichia virgilioides  4 0.040  3     0.148  1.375      0.001
11       1       Solanum lycocarpum  4 0.032  3     0.148  1.375      0.001
12       1       Erioteca pubescens  4 0.014  3     0.148  1.375      0.001
13       1     Pterodon emarginatus  2 0.087  2     0.074  0.687      0.003
14       2        Magonia pubescens  3 0.010  3     0.111  1.031      0.000
15       2      Dimorphandra molles  3 0.041  2     0.111  1.031      0.002
16       2    Byrsonima crassifólia  4 0.015  2     0.148  1.375      0.001
17       2        Spondias tuberosa  2 0.041  2     0.074  0.687      0.002
18       2     Maprounea guianensis  3 0.027  2     0.111  1.031      0.001
19       2           Dipteryx alata  3 0.070  1     0.111  1.031      0.003
20       2         Lafoensia pacari  2 0.011  2     0.074  0.687      0.000
21       2        Machaerium opacum  4 0.022  1     0.148  1.375      0.001
22       2     Simarouba versicolor  3 0.024  1     0.111  1.031      0.001
23       2        Palicourea rigida  2 0.020  1     0.074  0.687      0.001
24       2      Curatella americana  2 0.007  1     0.074  0.687      0.000
25       2    Plathymenia foliolosa  1 0.014  1     0.037  0.344      0.001
26       2           Andira inermis  1 0.011  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
27       2         Alibertia edulis  1 0.008  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
28       2  Terminalia brasiliensis  1 0.007  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
29       2       Protium spruceanum  1 0.007  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
30       2    Cecropia pachystachya  1 0.006  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
31       2      Vatairea macrocarpa  1 0.006  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
32       2       Vochysia elliptica  1 0.005  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
33       2       Qualea Grandiflora  1 0.003  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
34       2     Vernonia polysphaera  1 0.003  1     0.037  0.344      0.000
   DoR....  FA.... FR.... IVI....
1   51.857 100.000  7.407  75.072
2    8.561 100.000  7.407  42.428
3    7.599 100.000  7.407  33.563
4    4.503  66.667  4.938  15.627
5    6.804  66.667  4.938  15.178
6    4.624  83.333  6.173  14.233
7    0.661  83.333  6.173   9.239
8    0.932  50.000  3.704   7.041
9    0.678  50.000  3.704   6.787
10   1.046  50.000  3.704   6.125
11   0.827  50.000  3.704   5.906
12   0.364  50.000  3.704   5.442
13   2.273  33.333  2.469   5.430
14   0.263  50.000  3.704   4.998
15   1.055  33.333  2.469   4.555
16   0.392  33.333  2.469   4.235
17   1.067  33.333  2.469   4.223
18   0.706  33.333  2.469   4.206
19   1.811  16.667  1.235   4.076
20   0.290  33.333  2.469   3.446
21   0.565  16.667  1.235   3.174
22   0.611  16.667  1.235   2.876
23   0.507  16.667  1.235   2.429
24   0.179  16.667  1.235   2.101
25   0.365  16.667  1.235   1.943
26   0.283  16.667  1.235   1.861
27   0.199  16.667  1.235   1.777
28   0.186  16.667  1.235   1.764
29   0.174  16.667  1.235   1.752
30   0.162  16.667  1.235   1.740
31   0.151  16.667  1.235   1.729
32   0.140  16.667  1.235   1.718
33   0.083  16.667  1.235   1.661
34   0.083  16.667  1.235   1.661
```

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`. (Or `dtt2`.)

Comment: Ready, I included dtt2.

Answer (score 1):

In what follows I formated the data set `dtt2` using the `tidyverse`, it's much simpler and streamlined.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

data <- dtt2[c(2, 7, 9, 11)] %>%
  gather(Parametros, b, -Especie) %>%
  mutate(Parametros = case_when(
    grepl('^DR', Parametros) ~ 'Densidade Relativa',
    grepl('^DoR', Parametros) ~ 'Dominancia Relativa',
    grepl('^FR', Parametros) ~ 'Frequencia Relativa',
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

As for the `colour` and `facet_wrap`, I believe it makes more sense to group by `Parametros`, here is the code to do it.

```
margins = unit(c(1, 1, 3, 1), 'lines')

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(reorder(Especie, b), b, fill = Especie)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw(16)  +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Especies") + ylab("Indice de Valor de Importancia (%)") +
  labs(fill = "Parametros") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic",size=10), 
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.justification = c(0, 0),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x= element_text(size=10), 
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=12),
        plot.margin=margins,
        legend.position = c(-0.5,-0.2),
        legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  facet_wrap(~ Parametros)

gg
```

If you want to group (meaning, `colour` and `facet_wrap`) by `Especie`, the code could be like the following. The y axis is now `Parametros`. And I don't think this graph makes much sense, the real problem in the question is how to reshape data to long format.

```
gg2 <- ggplot(data, aes(reorder(Parametros, b), b, fill = Especie)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw(16)  +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Especies") + ylab("Indice de Valor de Importancia (%)") +
  labs(fill = "Parametros") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic",size=10), 
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.justification = c(0, 0),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x= element_text(size=10), 
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=12),
        plot.margin=margins,
        legend.position = c(0,-0.2),
        legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  facet_wrap(~ Especie)

gg2
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I group by stratum (column 1)? And I wanted the output as in the graph I made, where in the same bar are present the three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, thanks so much for the tidyverse tip. Now I have to make my y axis more spaced.

```
data <- dtt2[c(1, 2, 7, 9, 11)] %>%
  gather(Parametros, b, -Estrato, -Especie) %>%
  mutate(Parametros = case_when(
    grepl('^DR', Parametros) ~ 'Densidade Relativa',
    grepl('^DoR', Parametros) ~ 'Dominancia Relativa',
    grepl('^FR', Parametros) ~ 'Frequencia Relativa',
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))

ggplot(data, aes(reorder(Especie,b), b, fill = Parametros, colour=Estrato)) +
    geom_col(alpha = 0.8) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
    theme_bw(16)  +
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("Especies") + ylab("Indice de Valor de Importancia (%)") +
    labs(fill = "Parametros") +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic",size=10), legend.title=element_blank(),legend.justification = "left" ,legend.text=element_text(size=10),
          axis.text.x= element_text(size=10), axis.title.x=element_text(size=12),
          axis.title.y=element_text(size=12),
          plot.margin=margins,legend.position=c(-0.5,-0.2),legend.direction = "horizontal")+
    facet_wrap( ~ data[,1])
```